# Add text from a variable to a tweet

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to tweet text I get from a function executing a getJSON command, the tweet button I created opens twitter but with no text, I want it to automatically "paste" the quote the webpage is currently displaying. My basic html code is the following:

```
<button id="quoteClick" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg quoteButton text-center btn-block">Get Quote</button>

<div class="col-md-8 show boxed text-center"> Text </div>

<div class="col-md-5 text-center author"> auth
</div>

<a class="tw-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=" data-size="large" target="_blank">
    <button type="twbutton" class="btn btn-primary">Tweet quote</button>
</a>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  gQuote();

  function gQuote() {
    $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en",
      function(data) {
        var Quote = data.quoteText;
        var Author = data.quoteAuthor;
        var quoteShow = ""
        var quoteAuthor = ""
        quoteShow += "<h3 class='text-center'>" + Quote + "</h3>"
        quoteAuthor += "<h4 class='text-center'>" + Author + "</h4>"
        $(".show").html(quoteShow);
        $(".author").html(quoteAuthor);

      });

  };

  $("#quoteClick").on("click",function() {
    gQuote();
  });
  $(".tw-button").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("href",'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text='+ Quote);

  });
});
```

I understand that the `Quote` variable was created within the previous function and I am not clear as to how I can "carry" it towards the twitter button. 
I am using codepen so `"target:_blank"` is a must.

Comment: Consider this example: https://jsfiddle.net/L05c1c7y/1/ - Declaring a variable with `var` means it is only accessible within the local scope (The function `gQuote()` in your example). By removing `var`, you can access it globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Quote variable is local to the callback in the $.getJSON.
One (and the simplest) of the solutions is shifting the 'var Qoute' declaration to the callback of the $(document).ready callback, so that it is accessible to the '$(".tw-button").click' callback through the scope chain during the right hand search. Though, this is not very good for larger-scaled code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    gQuote();

    var Quote; //Declare variable here

    function gQuote() {
        $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(data) {

            Quote = data.quoteText; //Set it here

            var Author = data.quoteAuthor;
            var quoteShow = ""
            var quoteAuthor = ""
            quoteShow += "<h3 class='text-center'>" + Quote + "</h3>"
            quoteAuthor += "<h4 class='text-center'>" + Author + "</h4>"
            $(".show").html(quoteShow);
            $(".author").html(quoteAuthor);

      });
    };

    $("#quoteClick").on("click",function() {
        gQuote();
    });

    $(".tw-button").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("href",'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text='+ Quote);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken all you need to do is declare your variables `Quote` and `Author` outside `gQuote()` function. Inside `gQuote()` you can assign them whatever you wish and pass their latest values to `$(".tw-button").click()` event. **Make** sure you got JSON object and parsed data from it right.

---

I made something similar as freecodecamp project. Have a look [here](http://codepen.io/ilyaZin/pen/aJNZBo?editors=0010) if you have difficulties.